# Solve the inequality $3^{(x+3)^2}+\frac{1}{9}\leq 3^{x^2-2}+27^{2x+3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I tried to group the summands so that I could decompose them into multipliers, but nothing worked...

$$3^{(x+3)^2}+\frac{1}{9}\leq 3^{x^2-2}+27^{2x+3}\Leftrightarrow 3^{x^2+6x+9}+\frac{1}{9}\leq 3^{x^2-2}+3^{6x+9}$$
$$3^{x^2+6x+7}+1\leq 3^{x^2-4}+3^{6x+7}$$
How to solve it further?

Comment: Just an intuition, maybe you can rearrange the terms with $3^{x^2+6x+9}-3^{6x+9}\le 3^{x^2-2}-3^{-2}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by $9=3^2$,
\begin{align*}
3^{(x+3)^2}+\frac{1}{9}\leq 3^{x^2-2}+27^{2x+3}&\Longleftrightarrow 3^{(x+3)^2\color{red}{+2}}+1\leq 3^{x^2-2\color{red}{+2}}+3^{3(2x+3)\color{red}{+2}}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow 3^{x^2+6x+11}+1\leq 3^{x^2}+3^{6x+11}\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \left(3^{x^2}-1\right)\left(3^{6x+11}-1\right)\leq 0.
\end{align*}
Since $x^2\geq 0$, we have $3^{x^2}-1\geq 0$, so the inequality is equivalent to
$$3^{x^2}-1=0\ \ \text{ or }\ \ 3^{6x+11}-1\leq 0\Longleftrightarrow x=0 \ \ \text{ or }\ \ 6x+11\leq 0\Longleftrightarrow x=0 \ \ \text{ or }\ \  x\leq-\frac{11}6.$$
So the solutions of the inequality are
$$x\in\{0\}\bigcup \left(-\infty,-\frac{11}6\right].$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a calculation error... I wrote $9-2$ and I should have written $9+2$.

Comment: @Dmitry Yes. I wrote it in red color to emphasize your minor error, which made you fail to do the factorization. I'm glad that you've got my points.

Comment: @Dmitry Don’t forget that $x=0$ is also a solution to the inequality. You can cancel $3^{x^2}-1$ only if $x\ne0$.

Comment: @BernardPan Good point! Let me edit my answer... Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, I realized myself that there $-1$ should be there. Thank you for helping me figure out a silly mistake...

Comment: @Dmitry You're welcome. I'm glad to help :D

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can rewrite the inequality as follows: $(3^{6x+11}-1)(3^{x^2}-1) \le 0$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: How were you able to decompose it into multipliers? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Put $m = 3^{x^2}, n = 3^{6x+9} \implies mn + \dfrac{1}{9} \le \dfrac{1}{9}m+n\implies 9mn+1 \le m+9n \implies (9n-1)(m-1) \le 0$, and at this point you arrive at the product above in my post.